# How to construct custom type in a template class definition

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

Is it possible to use templates to costruct types in the type definition? E.g. I would like to have something like this:

```cpp
class MyType
{
    template<typename T>
    someNamespace::T Convert(someOtherNamespace::T value);
};
```

If templates cannot be engaged for this purpose, is such a declaration even possible?

Regards, Dawid

Comment: *Why* do you want this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not. Template parameters name actual types, not identifiers (which you would need if you wanted to do lookup in a namespace).

Also, I don't see how this is particularly useful. It requires that two namespaces contain types that have the same name and can be converted in a completely generic manner - how often will you see that?

Can you describe in more detail what you want to do?

Comment: I have to perform serialization between managed (c++/cli) and native types. For that I have a template serializer class:  `template<class managedType, class nativeType> ref class Serializer`. For most types it is easy to use templates but it would be much easier if I could define only the identifier istead of whole type since in both namespaces types have the same names.

Comment: @dawid: You may use MACRO...?

Comment: @Jarod42: aren't macros resolved before templates? If so, I have to instantiate template function using two types (got from macro). I'd like to have a function templated with one type (identifier) and perform exact types construction in the function (or class if a class were templated).

Comment: I think this is an answer and what I want to accomplish should be achieved in other way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you want, but maybe following (using macro) may help:

```
// Assuming value is of type someOtherNamespace::identifier 
#define CONVERT(identifier, value) static_cast<someNamespace::identifier>(value)
```